# Python Budget Automation - Create Multiple Workbooks with Different worksheets - XLSXwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter, openxlsx

For my company I am trying to automate the budget process. We have some VBA that is trying to do the job, but Python could in my view easily reduce the workload.

**Setting**
In our company we have multiple responsible budgetholders, each budgetholder is responsible for a number of business units. Every budgetholder receives an excel, that has a seperate sheet for every business unit they are resposible for. They fill in all the sheets, and send back the file. Python needs to create a predefined excel template, in which every budgetholder fills in the forecast of the business unit they are responsible for.

For simplicity, this is what the template looks like:

```
book = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Budget.xlsx")
s = book.add_worksheet("Budget")
s.write("B6","Account Number")
s.write("C6","Description")
s.write("D6","Budget")
s.write("B10","*")
s.write("C10","Revenue")
s.write("D10","=SUM(D7:D9)")
book.close()
```

In excel we have a list with all budgetholders and the business units they are responsible for:

| Budgetholder | Business Unit | Business Unit Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1140 | aa |
| Joe | 1141 | bb |
| Joe | 1142 | cc |
| Will | 1940 | ff |
| Will | 1941 | gg |

**Requirements**
Now python needs to create seperate excel files for each budgetholder;
Every budgetholder only receives the business units they are responsible for.
The business Unit should be in cell D1; The business unit description should be in cell D2.

For example, Joe receives an excel file with three worksheets.
Every worksheet has the same template, but in each worksheet there is a different business unit in cell D1 and D2.

The business units should all be reported according to the template that is stated above.

As there are so many requirements, I am a bit lost in the coding. As there will be many budgetholders and even more business units, some sort of iteration is needed. All help is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like a simple solution could be to create an empty excel template, that is just an empty budget file, then populate it with iterations over a dictionary that you either have in a script or you build by iterating over the table example you have given.

If you can provide some excel sheet examples of desired output, I can take a further look if needed.